# How to rotate an object first up to 30 then in the opposite direction to -30

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I make that the object rotates first to the left to 30 and then to the opposite side, that is, to the right to -30 and that this action is repeated
I tried to use this condition but it didn’t work. The object always rotated counterclockwise.

```
if (this.transform.rotation.z >= 30)
        {

            isCanRotate = true;
        }
        if (this.transform.rotation.z <= -30)
        {
            isCanRotate = false;
        }


            if (this.transform.rotation.z < 30 && isCanRotate == false) 
            {
               this.transform.Rotate(0, 0, Time.deltaTime * 30);
            }

            if(this.transform.rotation.z > -30 &&  isCanRotate == true)
            {
               this.transform.Rotate(0, 0, Time.deltaTime * -30);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public float RotationCar = 1;            
    private bool increase = true;


if (increase)
            {
                if (RotationCar < 1)
                    RotationCar += Time.deltaTime * 1;
                else
                    increase = false;
            }
            else
            {
                if (RotationCar > -1)
                    RotationCar -= Time.deltaTime * 1;
                else
                    increase = true;
            }

            this.transform.Rotate(0, 0, RotationCar);
```